# Azure DevSpaces Container cannot be reached

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-dev-spaces

I am getting an exception while starting the debugger for Azure Dev Spaces when using a fresh gRPC project from the template. The sample project on the quickstart .Net Core page for Azure DevSpaces debugs properly while my sample project does not within the same cluster. The sample project seems to use .Net Core 2.2 while my project uses 3.0. The following steps reproduce the issue:

1. Open Visual Studio 2019 (v16.2.3)
2. Click *Create a new project*
3. Search for *gRPC*
4. Click *ASP.NET Core Web Application*
5. Give the project any name
6. On the next screen, click *gRPC Service - A project
   template for creating a gRPC ASP.NET Core service.*
7. Create the project
8. Using the debug options, choose *Azure Dev Spaces* and configure the project to use the already set up cluster
9. Start the debugger using *Azure Dev Spaces*

Expected: Debugger remains attached after docker steps are complete.

Actual:

- Docker steps complete and a message that says *Waiting for container...* appears in the output window.
- After a short time, a message that says: *Service [service name] port 80 (HTTP) is available via port forwarding at [port]* appears in the output window.
- After that, the debugger gets detached and the following exception appears in the output window accompanied by an error modal that says the ***Container cannot be reached***:

```
An error occurred during warmup for project 'DebugSample':
System.InvalidOperationException: Container cannot be reached.
   at Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.Connection.ContainerConnector.<EnsureDevHostAgentConnectionAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.Connection.ContainerConnector.<ConnectAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.ManagementClients.ServiceManagementClientImplementation.<EnsureContainerConnectors>d__102.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.DevSpaces.Client.ManagementClients.ServiceManagementClientImplementation.<ExecuteNextIterationAsync>d__98.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Client.DevSpacesServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<StartDebugAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.<ExecuteOperationAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Client.DevSpacesServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<StartDebugAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.<ExecuteOperationAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.<ExecuteOperationAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.DebugService.<WarmupProjectAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.BackgroundWarmupService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<ExecuteWarmupAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.<ExecuteOperationAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Common.Logging.PerfLoggerExtensions.<ExecuteOperationAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.BackgroundWarmupService.<ExecuteWarmupAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.DevSpaces.Tools.Package.Services.BackgroundWarmupService.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<WarmupProject>b__5>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I'm running into similar issues, are you also behind a corporate http proxy?

Comment: @jbockle we do not have an HTTP proxy in the way. Our issue turned out to be caused by the fact Dev Spaces does not support HTTP/2.